# how to make UIImageView clickable and selectable visually

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to replicate experience of picking images in a grid view and making them selected once clicked. Only way I can think of right now is layering a second view on top of UIImageView and making it visible once UIImageView is selected. Is there a better pattern for this or some good examples?

Comment: Why not just use a UIButton?

Comment: If you use a `UICollectionView`, almost all of this is handled for you, including selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Teja says, you can set your image view's userInteractionEnabled flag to true, and then attach a tap gesture recognizer. That won't make it show visual feedback if it's tapped however.

The simplest way to do this is to use a UIButton instead of an image view. Set its type to custom, and install your image as the background image for the button. The UIButton class will highlight the button as it's tapped, and invoke the appropriate target/action when it's tapped. (Assuming you set up a target/action)

If you want different feedback than the standard highlight feedback you can load a custom "highlighted" image on the button and the button will display that image while the button is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tap gesture recogniser to the image view or else you can use buttons instead of imageviews!